# Circuitikz Current Source

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'd like to know if it is possible to place a current source that looks like the following:

[image: Current source]

Comment: Yes. You can do it yourself http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/bipole.pdf or give me a couple of days.  What exactly do you call this?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!  It's just a 'Current Source'!

Comment: I would like to add this to my collection, but I need to give it a name.  I read that this symbol is more common in Europe, but Europe is big place, and we already have a European current source.  I suppose I could give it an acronym (YAFCS) or something.

Comment: Hi, well I'm from Australia where this source is sometimes used.  Some datasheets also use it.  I just called it 'Iring'.  Curiously, how is it that you 'add it to your collection'?  Is there someone where I can just save the component so Circuitikz remembers it?

Comment: You can put the definition into a separate file and \input it in the header (sort of like \usepackage).  BTW, isourcebr it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\margins{0.2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
\screensize{3cm}{5cm}
\backgroundcolor{white}

% preparation to create bipoles

\makeatletter
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}

\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\makeatother 

\newlength{\ResUp} \newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft} \newlength{\ResRight}

% set default dohicky size

\ctikzset{bipoles/doohicky/height/.initial=.4}
\ctikzset{bipoles/doohicky/width/.initial=.6}

% create doohicky shape

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/doohicky/height}}
 {doohicky}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/doohicky/height}}
 {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/doohicky/width}}
 {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}

  \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\ResLeft}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.333\ResLeft}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0.667\ResRight}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}}
  \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.333\ResRight}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0.667\ResRight}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}}
  \pgfusepath{draw} %draw doohicky
    \pgfscope
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex'}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.667\ResLeft}{1.333\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.667\ResRight}{1.333\ResUp}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}   %draw arrow
    \endpgfscope
 }

% create doohicky to-path style

\def\doohickypath#1{\TikzBipolePath{doohicky}{#1}}
\tikzset{doohicky/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\doohickypath, l=#1}}

% end of setup

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[doohicky, l=I, o-*] (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't compile `<to be read again> 
                   \pgfk@/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length 
l.14 ...ysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}`

Comment: @viesturs - Circuitikz has changed since 2013.  More importantly, it now provides ioosoiurce, voosource and oosourcetrans (page 70).