# Help on Dutch current source symbol

Tags: circuitikz

I want to create a current source as seen in many Dutch book on electric circuits. The standard European conponent is not what I want. I want something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[I, l=$I_B$] (0,2);
\draw [->] (-0.5,0.65) -- (-0.5,1.35);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In the code, I draw the arrow (as part of the current source symbol) myself. But I would like to have a complete circuitikz symbol for it. Also, I want the arrow and the symbol $I_B$ next to the arrow a bit more to the left. I tried to look into the circuitikz code for current sources but I think my knowlegde is too poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the current source from circuitikz and added the arrow from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128123/circuitikz-current-source/128286?s=1%7C97.6864#128286) (more or less).

The label location is determined by the borders of the components and `[inner sep]`, so the easiest way to move the label is to just add space inside the label.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/isource/height}}{isource}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/isource/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/isource/width}}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
  \pgfscope
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex'}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{1.2\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@right}{1.2\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}   %draw arrow
  \endpgfscope
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{circuitikz}
%\tikzset{every node/.style={inner sep=1em}}
\draw (0,0) to[I, l={$I_B$~},name=A] (0,2);
%\draw[red] (A.sw) rectangle (A.ne);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

For more control, replace the label with a node:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[I, name=A] (0,2);
\node[left=2pt] at (A.n) {$I_A$};

\draw (0,0) to[I, name=B] (2,0);
\node[above=2pt] at (B.n) {$I_B$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The option `inner sep=1em` works when the current source is placed vertically, but not when it is placed horizontally. Is there another option?

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw If you like John's answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). It is the TeX.SE way of saying thank you.